# Платная зона доставки. Защита от изменения цены доставки в скрипте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Так как на frontend можно изменять скрипты, то возникает проблема в расчете цены доставки, ее можно изменить. Вот пример который показывает цену доставки в определенной выбранной зоне
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones/. Можно ли на backend реализовать какое нибудь решение ? Например адрес все же попадает в backend и уже на уровне backend можно куда, то его отправить для проверки суммы доставки

Comment: Для работы с API Яндекс Карт на сервере вам необходимо использовать коммерческие тарифы. А в этом случае можно просто выбрать API Маршрутизатора для вычисления дистанции и пользователям выводить результат. Если речь не об этом, в чём сложность использовать голые данные для проверки стоимости в скрипте? Может есть готовый пример и более точное описание сценария/проблемы?

Comment: @YaCor' У каждой зоны помеченной на карте статическая цена. Измерять дистанцию не вариант.  Не понял вопроса "в чём сложность использовать голые данные для проверки стоимости в скрипте?" можете пояснить ?

Comment: @YaCor' По поводу примера: Аякс запросом мы отправляем на сервер стоимость доставки выбранной зоны в любом случае, а в этом случае при отправки можно изменить цену доставки

Comment: Если дистанция по факту не требует определения, а цены фиксированы от выбранного района, в чём проблема передавать на сервер именно зону доставки, а не цену? В интерфейсе через API просто вычисляете целевой полигон и передавайте его через аякс. Цена будет спокойно определяться на серверной стороне, независимо от того, вносил правки мошенник в браузере или нет. А после можете её уже кидать пользователю в интерфейс - пусть хоть 100500 раз её после этого изменит.

Comment: @YaCor' Можете прислать пример ? Вы говорите о передачи зоны доставки на сервер, а в чем проблема эту зону изменить на клиентской стороне, а затем передать ? По факту на сервер только уходит адрес доставки, ну или координаты (без разницы).

Comment: Я уже на раз сталкивался с ситуациями, когда разработчики пытаются предотвратить некоторые потенциально проблемные кейсы и требуют методы дополнительной защиты их решения. Но внедрение подобных решений должно быть экономически обосновано. Одного лишь предположения, что кто-то может разобраться в вашем коде и использовать его для разовой экономии, недостаточно. Если у вас есть реальный сервис, реальная статистика по обману, которая приносит убытки - покажите. Если нет - это излишняя и чрезмерная перестраховка.

Comment: Ну и в дополнение к вышесказанному. Если вы хотите "абсолютно" защищённое решение - выполняйте его на серверной стороне, закрытой от внешних пользователей. Любой скрипт в пользовательском браузере потенциально уязвим. Однако коммерческие решения в том числе у Яндекса стоят денег. Использовать их при прочих равных почти наверняка окажется дороже, чем риск (или даже реальные разовые кейсы) "взлома кода".